# Add both margins to facet_grid but not the combination

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I want to show both the right and the bottom margin, but not the combination of both. Is this possible with facet_grid?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, group = vs)) + 
  geom_density() + 
  facet_grid(am ~ vs, switch = "y", margins = TRUE)
```

I tried to fix it by manually providing the factors to the `margin` argument but that doesn't help. Also, the R Documentation does not help me.

**Current outcome**

[image: The current outcome]

**Desired outcome**

[image: The desired outcome]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ggplot2 uses fixed idioms for naming key plot elements so we can use that deterministic condition to find the elements:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, group = vs)) + 
  geom_density() + 
  facet_grid(am ~ vs, switch = "y", margins = TRUE) -> gg
```

Build the plot into a `gtable` object:

```
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(gg))
```

Get the table cell names:

```
cells <- gt$layout$name
```

Figure out which one is the bottom corner panel and axis:

```
apply(
  apply(
    do.call(rbind, strsplit(grep("panel", cells, value=TRUE), "-"))[,2:3],
    2, as.integer), 
  2, max
) -> max_col_row

bottom_right_panel <- paste0(c("panel", max_col_row), collapse="-")
bottom_axis <- sprintf("axis-b-%s", max_col_row[2])
```

Figure out which ones are not the bottom corner panel:

```
paste0(
  grep(sprintf("^%s|%s$", bottom_corner, bottom_axis), cells, value=TRUE, invert = TRUE),
  collapse = "|"
) -> not_bottom_corner_panel
```

Only draw those:

```
grid::grid.draw(
  gtable::gtable_filter(gt, sprintf("^(%s)$", not_bottom_corner_panel))
)
```

Comment: your solution still keeps the x axis labels + ticks for the "bottom right" which is not desired. Mebbe I'm mistaken.

Comment: thx. fixed. it's still deterministic :-) That also helped make the example code less of an twisted parenthetical maze.

Comment: I updated my trial and error sentence to be more meaningful.

Comment: And the "take a guess" answer gets the tick box. Yep SO is def on the decline.

Answer (score 7):

such things are trial an error for me since I don't see the bigger pictures how the entries in `gt` relate to the end form:

```
library(ggplot2)

p<-
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, group = vs)) + 
    geom_density() + 
    facet_grid(am ~ vs, switch = "y", margins = TRUE)

gt = ggplotGrob(p)

keep <- !grepl("[3br]-3$",gt$layout$name)

gt$layout <- gt$layout[keep,]
gt$grobs  <- gt$grobs[keep]

plot(gt)
```

[image]